# Codelite:Hover Tooltip Does Not Work When Using Functors in C++

Tags: c++, tooltip, functor, codelite

I'm using functors in my C++ programs and I noticed that when I hover over the variable `object1` that I created it does not show its type.

I am attaching a screenshot of my program.

In VS Code it shows the type of the variable `object1` as `void(*function)(int)` when I hover over `object1`. I have enabled the tooltip options in settings. It should show the variable type as `void(*function)(int)` when I hover over it.

Is it possible in Codelite?

```
#include "vector.h"

void print(int v){
    std::cout<<v<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto object1=print;
    object1(66);
    return 0;
}
```

[screenshot of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyO6G.png)